# How to properly align pictures in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have 3 icons that i want to align them in the center i tried different code but nothing is working so far, i tried putting a margin right to it, but the problem with that is that it's adding an unnecessary space between them, so i want them to be close to each other, is there a way to put margin-right to it and remove the space from there ?
i just want to align them below my paragraph but in the center of it.
heres my code so far.

```css
    #body a img {
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      margin-top: 50px;
      margin-right: 200px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="body">
  <p class="text">We are a group of friends that enjoy playing League Of Legends togather, feel free to follow us on our different website medias</p>
  <div class="icons">
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/themunkiuke">
      <img class="icon1" src="images/youtube.png">
    </a>
    <a href="http://www.twitch.tv/siminios">
      <img class="icon2" src="images/twitch.png">
    </a>
    <a href="http://yinochi.deviantart.com/gallery/">
      <img class="icon3" src="images/art.png">
    </a>
  </div>
```

Comment: display:table; add this

Comment: Using such general selectors as `#body a img` just to center specific group of images is way too bad. Try to be more specific. `.icons { text-align: center; }` should be enough here.

Answer (score 1):

Will it be a simple `text-align` missing ?

```css
#body a img {
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
    }
.icons {
  text-align:center;
  }
```

```html
<div id="body">
  <p class="text">We are a group of friends that enjoy playing League Of Legends togather, feel free to follow us on our different website medias</p>
  <div class="icons">
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/themunkiuke">
      <img class="icon1" src="images/youtube.png">
    </a>
    <a href="http://www.twitch.tv/siminios">
      <img class="icon2" src="images/twitch.png">
    </a>
    <a href="http://yinochi.deviantart.com/gallery/">
      <img class="icon3" src="images/art.png">
    </a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you are ***[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Microsmsm/9d2dvcqj/1/)***

```css
#body a img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.icons {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="body">
  <p class="text">We are a group of friends that enjoy playing League Of Legends togather, feel free to follow us on our different website medias</p>
  <div class="icons">
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/themunkiuke">
      <img class="icon1" src="images/youtube.png">
    </a>
    <a href="http://www.twitch.tv/siminios">
      <img class="icon2" src="images/twitch.png">
    </a>
    <a href="http://yinochi.deviantart.com/gallery/">
      <img class="icon3" src="images/art.png">
    </a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a demo https://jsfiddle.net/r4wwczao/

In HTML I added a container for each icon to give them a percent size (the border is just to see the solution better):

```
<div id="body">
  <p class="text">We are a group of friends that enjoy playing League Of Legends togather, feel free to follow us on our different website medias </p>
  <div class="icons">
    <div class="icon_div">
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/themunkiuke"><img class="icon1" src="images/youtube.png"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="icon_div">
    <a href="http://www.twitch.tv/siminios"><img class="icon2" src="images/twitch.png"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="icon_div">
    <a href="http://yinochi.deviantart.com/gallery/"><img class="icon3" src="images/art.png"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
img{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

.icon_div{
  border:1px black solid;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width:32%;
}
```